# ggpubR "Can only handle data with groups that are plotted on the x-axis"

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

When running the following with ggpubr, i receive the error

> "Error in f(...) : Can only handle data with groups that are plotted on the x-axis"

```
my_comparisons <- list( c('A_1538_C', '1594delete12') )
ggplot(dt) +
geom_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0, aes(
    x=reorder(allele,mu_normal),
    y=mu_normal)) + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle =60, vjust = 1, hjust=1)) +
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons, method = "t.test")
```

`stat_compare_means` is functioning in another plot of mine, and this is not the issue others have run into when x is an interaction of terms. (details on that issue here: https://github.com/const-ae/ggsignif/issues/16 )

the value of

```
unique(dt$allele)
```

is

```
[1] A_1714_C     C_1721_A     G_1546_T     A_443_T      C_1535_T     A_1538_C    
[7] 1594delete12 rpoB_1547A.G rpoB_1534T.C WT           rpsL_128A.G  rpsL_263A.G 
[13] gyrA_248C_T 
15 Levels: 1594delete12 A_1538_C A_1714_C A_443_T blank C_1535_T ... rpsL_263A.G
```

so it seems like `my_comparisons` is a set of existing terms? (I'd like to expand to more comparisons when it's working)

Comment: You've put your `aes()` mapping into `geom_jitter()` - I'm not sure `stat_compare_means` will be able to access that information as it's specific to that geom. Try moving `aes()` into the `ggplot()` call.

Comment: thank you, Marius! this solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54190278/ggpubr-can-only-handle-data-with-groups-that-are-plotted-on-the-x-axis#comment95208774_54190278) it seems that this messages come from not being able to find the right data for the comparison. A solution is to add the aesthetics in ggplot or duplicate it and add it to `stat_compare_means` besides the `geom_*` function used.