# How to resolve problem with ggplot and ggsignif

Tags: r

I am trying to plot the differences in pairs. I found an example on this forum, but to this graph I would like to add the significance level information using the geom_signif function.
Unfortunately, I get the message back:
"Error in f (...):
Can only handle data with groups that are plotted on the x-axis "
Can someone help me fix this problem?

```
d <- data.frame(y = rnorm(20, 9, 2),
                group = as.factor(rep(c('Post-FAP', 'Post-DEP'), each = 10)),
                id = rep(1:10, 2))

ggplot(d, aes(y = y)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = rep(c(-2.5, 2.5), each = 10), group = group), fill = '#47E3FF') +
  geom_point(aes(x = rep(c(-1, 1), each = 10)), shape = 21, size = 1.5, col = "black", fill = "grey") +
  geom_line(aes(x = rep(c(-1, 1), each = 10), group = id)) +
  #geom_signif(annotation = "p=0.05", y_position = 13, xmin = -2.5, xmax = 2.5, tip_length = .02) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(-2.5, 2.5), labels = c("Post-FAP", "Post-DEP")) +
  scale_y_continuous(minor_breaks = seq(5, 14, by =1),
                     breaks = seq(6, 14, by = 2), limits = c(5, 14),
                     guide = "axis_minor") + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "none", panel.grid = element_blank())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to do is install `ggh4x`. It is an addon to `ggplot2` that has some helpful tools, like properly adding ticks and minor ticks in your case. Once you load the R package then you should be good to go.

Edit:

The reason that you were getting that error was that you were not specifying `group()` for `ggsignif`

```
library(ggh4x)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsignif)

ggplot(d, aes(y = y)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = rep(c(-2.5, 2.5), each = 10), group = group), fill = '#47E3FF') +
  geom_point(aes(x = rep(c(-1, 1), each = 10)), shape = 21, size = 1.5, col = "black", fill = "grey") +
  geom_line(aes(x = rep(c(-1, 1), each = 10), group = id)) +
  geom_signif(d, mapping = aes(x=id, y=y,group=group),annotation = "p=0.05", y_position = 13, xmin = -2.5, xmax = 2.5, tip_length = .02) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(-2.5, 2.5), labels = c("Post-FAP", "Post-DEP")) +
  scale_y_continuous(minor_breaks = seq(5, 14, by =1),
                     breaks = seq(5, 14, by = 2), limits = c(5, 14),
                     guide = "axis_minor") + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "none", panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image: example]

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint, but I can't enter the right code. Could you please help me?

Comment: @alunats what do you mean by "I can't enter the ride code?"

Comment: I mean, despite loading the ggh4x package, I still can't get a horizontal line with p value information

Comment: @alunats I apologize, I didn't see that part of the question. I updated my answer for you.

Comment: Thank you very much :-) You are great!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54190278/ggpubr-can-only-handle-data-with-groups-that-are-plotted-on-the-x-axis) on the error message you posted, saying that all the information on aes (x and y) need to be accessible by the subfunction, i.e. `geom_signif`.

Using `ggplot(d, x=aes(as.numeric(group), y=y, group = group))` worked for me.

Interestingly, `ggplot(d, x=aes(rep(c(-2.5, 2.5), each = 10), y=y, group = group))` , did not return an error, but also did not show the `geom_signif` annotation.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help with my problem. The best solution was to use the ggh4x package indicated by a colleague in the post above.

Comment: yes, I also had to load ggh4x for the  guide = "axis_minor" part,  a neat package I did not know of before,  - glad that it got resolved!